# Firebase crash reporting from other country

Tags: firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have an android project that uses  Firebase crash reporting. I have distributed the apk to friend who stays in different country.Now, I could see the crash report whenever my app crashes but no reports when my friend's app crashes.Is it because of the location ?

Comment: Some countries may firewall off parts of the internet from their residents.  It's impossible to know for sure in your case because you haven't specified which country, or other circumstances that may affect the outcome of a crash.

Comment: I am in India and my friend is in Germany.

Comment: @Nikki found any solution??? i have the same issue. please do share if you have got it.